# math puzzle: 4 digit number times 3

Tags: puzzle

A four-digit number $\overline{abcd}$, and a five-digit number $\overline{efghi}$, where $a,b, c, ..., i$ are from 1-9 and are distinct. We have

$\overline{abcd}*3=\overline{efghi}$.

What are $a, b, ..., i$?

What I have tried: I can deduce that $\overline{efghi}$ must be divisible by 9, but then the enumeration does not give the answer? Can this hold at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By exhaustive search there are two solutions:

$$5823\cdot 3 = 17469$$
$$5832\cdot 3 = 17496$$